# Isolating additives in alcohol products

Tags: home-experiment, evaporation

Given an alcohol-water solution (Liquor products) that may have additives and/or may have been aged in wood, I'd like to boil off the alcohol and the water to leave behind the various additives in a highly repeatable fashion.

I.e. a pan on the stove works OK, but I'd potentially like to throw together something a bit more precise.

Two lines of thinking so far.   Starting with the same amount of solution in both cases:

1. Use test tubes and a heater block.   Hold the temp at ~180ºF to evaporate the alcohol.  ~212ºF to evaporate the water.   That should concentrate the additives in the bottom of the tube.
2. Place a some sort of sample paper (?) that exactly covers the bottom of a container.  That should concentrate everything into the paper.

I'm really looking for:

1. Keywords to search for.   Been a long long long time since I spent time in a science lab of any sort and I don't know what I'm looking for or what is available.    I don't want to throw tons of money at this-- it is just a bit of a personal exploration thing-- but I don't mind spending some $$$ to create a repeatable, quantifiable, process for doing this sort of thing.
2. Any suggestions on process.  I could be entirely missing the obvious easy solution here because I don't know what I'm doing. :)
3. A process that potentially creates samples that can be sealed in something -- ziplock bags, perhaps? -- for later reference.   The sample paper process seems to be a better fit for this.

Comment: You don't want to keep *any* of the volatiles, that might significantly contribute to flavor?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Specifically, I want to take already made product and get rid of the alcohol / water -- the volatiles -- to see/taste/smell what is left behind.   Ideally, I'd like to do this in a repeatable fashion.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nope, I do not!  I want to specifically focus on the non-volatile additives that may be in play.   Really, I want to focus on everything but the alcohol and water.